# How does DefaultControllerFactory Handle Content Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

I'm working with the ASP.Net MVC 3 framework and I'm integrating dependency injection into the application. I'm trying to create a custom controller factory. The biggest issue I'm having at this moment is my implementation of IControllerFactory.CreateController gets passed requests for things like css, javascript, and other content files which subsequently causes it to throw an exception as the type for "Scripts/html5.js" doesn't exist. The code was inherited to me, so save any criticism you may have as to the very haphazard state. Here is the implementation:

```
    public virtual IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        if (requestContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestContext");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty", "controllerName");
        }

        this.RequestContext = requestContext;
        try
        {
            return container.Resolve<IController>(controllerName.ToLower());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
            return innerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ASP .NET MVC controllers don't handle requests for static files. That should be done by routing, which hands it off to IIS. I'd start by looking there.

Comment: Requests for static items that **don't** exist **do** get passed to the MVC controller factory. The default factory ignores them, but when you override it you have to also ignore them.

Comment: Isn't the actual problem that your pages are linking to missing resources? That will always happen to some extend because bots and spammers will try and access all sorts of files on your site. I think the answer in this case is not to log the error? Your solution below, while being cleaner doesn't solve this issue, well expect that you have changed the behaviour for the missing controller to a 404 which is probably correct, but could just as easily have been done with the original code.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by inheriting from the `DefaultControllerFactory` instead of implementing IControllerFactory in its entirety:

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
```

Then I only needed to override the `GetControllerInstance` method to hook in and return any instances from my Unity container:

```
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        IController controller = null;
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, String.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found or it does not implement IController.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }

        if (!typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Type requested is not a controller: {0}", controllerType.Name), "controllerType");
        }

        try
        {
            if (this.container.IsRegistered(controllerType))
            {
                controller = this.container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
            }
            else
            {
                controller = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Error resolving controller {0}", controllerType.Name, ex));
        }

        return controller;
    }
```

Comment: This seems a cleaner solution to me, since as you say you don't have to re-implement the entire factory. However when I just tried it, it doesn't solve the problem in the question because requests for missing static items still arrive, except the controller-type is now null, so you'll get a log message for every missing static item.

Comment: Also by using GetControllerInstance instead of CreateController you lose the value of the name field in the Unity mapping and have to use the type instead. e.g. my mapping is `<register type="System.Web.Mvc.IController" mapTo="MyMvcProject.Controllers.HomeController" name="Home" />` and in my controller factory, CreateController, I can use `return _container.Resolve<IController>(controllerName);` to resolve the controller. Which seems more consistent with the controller naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can try here:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.css"); //plus others if you have specifics
```

or better yet just try

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I was looking for a less invasive solution.

Comment: maybe I missed the point, but less invasive then telling mvc to not route static content via  built in mechanism? You want this handled at a routing layer rather than any static files getting any code executed for any controller factory code.